# JOptionPane - Erro botão cancelar

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de caixa eletrônico por `JFrame`, entretanto quando utilizo um `JOptionPane`, quando clico no botão *cancelar* ele aparece alguns erros no console do Eclipse.

Segue os erros abaixo:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at CaixaEletronico.CaixaEletronico.sacar(CaixaEletronico.java:150)
    at CaixaEletronico.GUI$2.actionPerformed(GUI.java:66)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

O código:

```
do {
    valorTotal = ((caixa[0][1]*100)+(caixa[1][1]*50)+(caixa[2][1]*20)+(caixa[3][1]*10)+(caixa[4][‌​1]*5)+(caixa[5][1]*2));
    valorSaque = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite valor de saque:"));
    if(valorSaque == 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Digite um valor para efetuar o saque!");
    } else{
        if(valorTotal < cotaMin){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Caixa Vazio: Chame o Operador");
            return null;
        }
        if(valorSaque > valorTotal){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saque não realizado por falta de cédulas");
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o seu código em mãos, fica mais fácil. Veja a correção:

```
valorTotal = ((caixa[0][1] * 100) + (caixa[1][1] * 50) + (caixa[2][1] * 20) + (caixa[3][1] * 10) + (caixa[4][‌​1] * 5) + (caixa[5][1] * 2));
int valorSaque = 0;
valorSaqueString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite valor de saque:");
if (valorSaqueString == null) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ação cancelada");
} else if ((valorSaque = Integer.parseInt(valorSaqueString)) == 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Digite um valor para efetuar o saque!");
} else {
    if (valorTotal < cotaMin) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Caixa Vazio: Chame o Operador");
        return null;
    }
    if (valorSaque > valorTotal) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saque não realizado por falta de cédulas");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No seu código deve haver algo assim:

```
int valor = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite um número"));
```

Ou então assim:

```
String digitado = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite um número");
int valor = Integer.parseInt(digitado);
```

Acontece, que se você clicar no botão cancelar, o `showInputDialog` vai retornar `null` e ao tentar fazer `Integer.parseInt(null)`, um `NumberFormatException` é lançado. Eis o que você pode fazer para contornar isso:

```
String digitado = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite um número");
if (digitado == null) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cancelado...");
} else {
    int valor = Integer.parseInt(digitado);
    // ...
}
```

Ou então:

```
String digitado = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite um número");
int valor = digitado == null ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(digitado);
```

---

O seu código contém isso:

```
valorSaque = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite valor de saque:"));
```

Para arrumar, basta usar isso no lugar:

```
String digitado = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite valor de saque:");
valorSaque = digitado == null ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(digitado);
```

Comment: Victor utilizando o método acima informado teria que mudar muita coisa em meu código, na realidade gostaria de saber se tem algo mais simples, questão de comando entende. Caso deseja ver o código segue o mesmo abaixo:

Comment: @PauloHenriqueGallo Então, poste o código. Caso contrário fica difícil adivinhar o que está acontecendo nele, não acha?

Comment: @PauloHenriqueGallo É melhor você editar a pergunta e colocar o código lá. Assim dá para ter certeza que ele está certo. Entretanto, eu já atualizei a minha resposta. Apenas fica a dica que perguntas como a sua normalmente são fechadas pois é difícil se saber o que está acontecendo, uma vez que ela não mostra o código, e isso faz com que a pergunta seja difícil de ser respondida. Então fica a dica para a próxima vez.